# Input.GetKeyDown not working

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get an input from the "space" button, but it looks like it doesn't take the input when I click. Here's my code:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "GreenKey") {
        print ("Green Key taken");
        Destroy (other.gameObject);
        greenKey_canvas.enabled = true;
    } else if (other.gameObject.tag == "RedKey") {
        print ("Red Key taken");
        Destroy (other.gameObject);
        redKey_canvas.enabled = true;
    } else if (other.gameObject.tag == "YellowKey") {
        print ("Yellow Key taken");
        Destroy (other.gameObject);
        yellowKey_canvas.enabled = true;
    } else if (other.gameObject.tag == "Gem") {
        print ("Gem taken");
        gems = gems + 5;
        gemsText.text = gems.ToString ();
        Destroy (other.gameObject);
    } else if (other.gameObject.tag == "RedGem") {
        print ("Gem taken");
        gems++;
        gemsText.text = gems.ToString ();
        Destroy (other.gameObject);
    } else if (other.gameObject.tag == "LiveTaker") {
        lives--;
    } else if (other.gameObject.tag == "RedDoor") {
        if (redKey_canvas.enabled) {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {


            //OPEN DOOR
            other.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = enterDoor;
            redKey_canvas.enabled = false;
            }
        }
    } else if (other.gameObject.tag=="YellowDoor") {
        if (yellowKey_canvas.enabled) {
            //OPEN DOOR
        }
    } else if (other.gameObject.tag=="GreenDoor") {
        if (greenKey_canvas.enabled) {
            //OPEN DOOR
        }
    }
}
```

In the console, I get the "entered door with key" message, but when I press Space, nothing happens.

I've also tried to add an Axis to the Input Manager named "DoorEnter", but it doesn't work either...

Comment: You may want to post the complete function that contains this code or even the whole code. Its hard to help with just this.

Comment: just edited @Programmer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this dosent work, is that the OnCollisionEnter function only activates the frame that the collision first happens, and that the GetKeyDown only lauches the single frame the button gets pushed.

One quite ugly fix, would be to Replace GetKeyDown with GetKey, then already hold space when walking into the door.

A better solution would be to add a variable, for an if statement in the Update loop. Make it activate when the user enters, and deactivate when the user leaves collision area.

Then make an if statement like this:

```
if(inCollider && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){
//Open door here
}
```

Also, can anyone format this correctly? (Am on phone)

EDIT: Collision means trigger! Sorry!